# RT5370 SH4 Cross Compile Driver Errors

Tags: driver

I try to build 2.5.0.3 driver from file [2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5016) to RT5370 chipset.

Install STLinux 2.4 under Ubuntu 10.04.4 x32, make under kernel linux-sh4-2.5.32.59_stm24_0211. But I wrote /opt/STM/STLinux-2.2/devkit/sources/kernel/linux-sh4-2.5.32.59_stm24_0211 in path instead of STLinux-2.4, because Makefile have some defects:

```
install:
ifeq ($(TARGET), LINUX)
ifneq (,$(findstring 2.4,$(LINUX_SRC)))
$(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.4 install
else
$(MAKE) -C $(RT28xx_DIR)/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install
endif
endif
```

The mention in a path 2.4 build a kernel as 2.4 that in my case a mistake.

Wrote in Makefile:

```
PLATFORM = ST
...
LINUX_SRC = /opt/STM/STLinux-2.2/devkit/sources/kernel/linux-sh4-2.5.32.59_stm24_0211
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/STM/STLinux-2.2/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-
```

In ./os/linux/config.mk wrote:

```
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
CC := sh4-linux-gcc
LD := sh4-linux-ld
```

Build at run make command. But have the error:

```
script/Makefile.build:49: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/home/vitaliy/drv_src/os/linux/Makefile". Fix it to use EXTRA_CFLAGS.
```

Founded strings at ./os/linux/config.mk:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),ST)
CFLAGS := -D__KERNEL__ -I$(LINUX_SRC)/include -I$(RT28xx_DIR)/include -Wall -O2 -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -ffreestanding -m4-nofpu -o $(WFLAGS) 
export CFLAGS
endif
```

And change CFLAGS to EXTRA_CFLAGS in them.

Again error:

```
sh4-linux-gcc: error: -pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible.
```

Ok. Remove flag -fomit-frame-pointer.

Again error:

```
error: cpu/cache.h: No such file or directory.
```

In string:

```
WFLAGS := -DAGGREGATION_SUPPORT -DPIGGYBACK_SUPPORT -DWMM_SUPPORT -DLINUX -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs
```

Remove flag -DLINUX.

Again error with unknown types (for example: ./os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.c:638:1: error: unknown type name 'VOID' and so on with types 'UCHAR', 'ULONG' etc).

Second way to build with help of

KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make without changes in sources files of drivers.

Error in this case too:

```
./os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.c:28:23: fatal error: rt_config.h: No such file or directory.
```

What is wrong in my building? Or can I fix sources code and build driver for SH4-platform.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I recently got myself the same adapter, and I was trying to cross compile for ARM, and run into the same problem.

Basically, you just have to add the include folder from the root of the driver package.

I did these modifications to get it working:

in `DRIVER_DIR/Makefile`, added:

```
PLATFORM = MYPLATFORM
```

All other platforms are commented out.

Later in same file:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MYPLATFORM)
    LINUX_SRC = /DIR_TO_MY_KERNEL_SRC/freescale_mainline/linux-mainline
    CROSS_COMPILE =  /DIR_TO_MY_CROSS_COMPILER/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-
    CROSS_COMPILE_INCLUDE = /DRIVER_DIR/include /*Might not be necessary*/
endif
```

Then in `DRIVER_DIR/os/linux/config.mk`, added:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MYPLATFORM)
    EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(WFLAGS) -I$(RT28xx_DIR)/include
endif
```

Also, please note that in your kernel configuration you need to have couple of flags enabled:

```
CONFIG_WEXT_CORE=y
CONFIG_WEXT_PROC=y
CONFIG_WEXT_SPY=y
CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV=y
```

You can find them under `Device Drivers-->Network Device Support-->Wireless LAN-->IEEE 802.11 for Host AP`

I compile it just like this now:

```
DRIVER_DIR$ ARCH=arm make
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are a hero sir. I was missing CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV=y! +1